# Change directory of the saved file inside another file. Clean and neat. No mess

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, save

I've done a program for *register* and *login* but the data file the program saved is the same directory as the program file. How to change the directory for saved file into a new file so that it won't be a mess. This is my program( a newbie though).

```
import pickle
while True:
    RegOrLog = raw_input('[Register/Login]:')
    if RegOrLog not in ('reg', 'register', 'REGISTER','log', 'login', 'LOGIN',\
                        'r','l'):
        print "Please enter 'register' if you dont have account"
        print "Please enter 'login' if you already registered"

    if RegOrLog in ('reg', 'register', 'REGISTER','r','Register'):
        count = 0
        while count < 1:
            regusrnm = raw_input('Enter your desire login name:')
            regusrnm = regusrnm.lower()
            regpswrd = raw_input('Enter your password:')
            while True:
                regage = raw_input('Enter your age:')
                if int(regage) not in range(1, 100):
                    print 'please enter apropriate value'
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                reggender = raw_input('State your gender:')
                if reggender not in ('male', 'female'):
                    print 'Are you an alien?'
                else:
                    break

            data = {"username": regusrnm, "password": regpswrd, "age": regage,\
                    "gender": reggender}
            pickle.dump( data, open( regusrnm, "wb" ) )
            RegOrLog = 'login'
            print 'Please login to your account for security purpose'
            break

    if RegOrLog in ('log', 'login', 'LOGIN','l','Login'):
        logusrnm = raw_input('Enter your username:')
        data = pickle.load( open( logusrnm, "rb" ) )
        count = 3
        while count >= 1:
            logpswrd = raw_input('Enter your password:')
            count = count - 1
            if logpswrd != data["password"]:
                print "You have",count, "attempt left"
                if count == 0:
                    print "The account doesn't exist or wrong password"
                    print 'Please register a new one'
                    break

            else:
                 print 'Welcome Back',data["username"]
                 break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to create a separate file for each user. Use a database or a single file to hold user information and any solution to this problem will be hacky but if you still want to do that however you are doing it, do something like this:

```
import pickle, os
user_folder = "user_data/"
if not os.path.exists(user_folder):
    os.makedirs(user_folder)
while True:
    RegOrLog = raw_input('[Register/Login]:')
    if RegOrLog not in ('reg', 'register', 'REGISTER','log', 'login', 'LOGIN',\
                        'r','l'):
        print "Please enter 'register' if you dont have account"
        print "Please enter 'login' if you already registered"

    if RegOrLog in ('reg', 'register', 'REGISTER','r','Register'):
        count = 0
        while count < 1:
            regusrnm = raw_input('Enter your desire login name:')
            regusrnm = regusrnm.lower()
            regpswrd = raw_input('Enter your password:')
            while True:
                regage = raw_input('Enter your age:')
                if int(regage) not in range(1, 100):
                    print 'please enter apropriate value'
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                reggender = raw_input('State your gender:')
                if reggender not in ('male', 'female'):
                    print 'Are you an alien?'
                else:
                    break

            data = {"username": regusrnm, "password": regpswrd, "age": regage,\
                    "gender": reggender}
            pickle.dump( data, open( user_folder + regusrnm, "wb" ) )
            RegOrLog = 'login'
            print 'Please login to your account for security purpose'
            break

    if RegOrLog in ('log', 'login', 'LOGIN','l','Login'):
        logusrnm = raw_input('Enter your username:')
        data = pickle.load( open( user_folder + logusrnm, "rb" ) )
        count = 3
        while count >= 1:
            logpswrd = raw_input('Enter your password:')
            count = count - 1
            if logpswrd != data["password"]:
                print "You have",count, "attempt left"
                if count == 0:
                    print "The account doesn't exist or wrong password"
                    print 'Please register a new one'
                    break

            else:
                 print 'Welcome Back',data["username"]
                 break
```

Comment: haha. its only for my university assignment. thank btw for sharing your idea

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not saved "in the same directory as the program", it's saved in whatever is the current directory when the script is executed. And the way to store the file elsewhere is quite simple and obvious: just explicitely pass the full absolute path you want your file to be saved in to `open()`.

Comment: can you give me an example how to save the file? sorry for my bad english though

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand in "just explicitely pass the _full absolute path_ you want your file to be saved in to open()." ?  `f = open("blah.txt")` will lookup a file named "'blah.txt" in the current working directory (usually the directory you where in when you launched your script). `f = open("/home/bigb/blah.txt")` will lookup a file named "blah.txt" in the "/home/bigb/" directory. No rocket science here ;)

Comment: oohhhh~ now i understand. that is the answer that i want. thank you